# What happens during under-modulation?

Tags: electrical-engineering, signal-processing

I need clarification regarding what exactly happens to the information in amplitude modulation if it is [under-modulated](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=under+modulation). I know that if it is over-modulated, some information will not reach the receiving end (distortion), which can cause unintelligible sounds or scrambled video. Additionally, there is noise present. However, I cannot seem to grasp what exactly is the effect of under-modulation on the information? Is it not just the same as that of a perfect-modulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer—I'm not qualified to give a longer one:

Practical analog signal paths always are [*noisy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_(signal_processing)). Reducing the modulation level will also reduce the [*signal-to-noise ratio*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio). That makes it harder for the receiver to recover the desired information.